# Entity framework 6 use parentid in where clause with lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I'm new to EF and want to get an entry from my database (SQLite) in the following way:

Classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; } = new List<Month>();
}

public class Month
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CacheId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Month> Months { get; set; }
```

Usage:

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext())
{
  var customer = context.Customers.First();
  context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
  var shouldContainOneEntry = context.Months.Where(x => x.Customer.Id == customer.Id).ToList();
}
```

shouldContainOneEntry is emtpy, but a test with a delegate and a static variable  instead of the lambda expression worked:

```
    private static Guid staticGuid;
    public static bool DelegateTest(Month x)
    {
        return staticGuid == x.Customer.Id;
    }
    ...
    staticGuid = customer.Id;
    var workingVersion = context.Months.Where(DelegateTest).ToList();
```

The generated SQL looks correct:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CacheId] AS [CacheId], 
[Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Extent1].[Customer_Id] AS [Customer_Id]
FROM [Months] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Customer_Id] = @p__linq__0

-- p__linq__0: '5cfde6e0-5b3f-437b-84c8-2845b077462d' (Type = AnsiStringFixedLength, IsNullable = false)
```

Why is the version with the lambda expression not working?

Comment: are you using code first?

Comment: Must be something related to SQLLite query provider. When you execute the "delegate version", you are calling `Enumerable.Where`, which means the whole table is read in memory and then filtered. The "lambda version" should be generating the SQL you've shown. Looks like SQLLite has no native `Guid` support, and the string conversion could be wrong. What happens if you execute `SELECT * FROM Months WHERE Customer_Id = '5cfde6e0-5b3f-437b-84c8-2845b077462d'` directly in your database?

Comment: @Hadi Hassan: Yes I'm using code first and the generated tables look fine.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Yes you are right, the problem is that SQLite has no native Guid support. I tested the code:    var shouldBeOneEntry = context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == customer.Id).ToList();  and the result is an emtpy list. I think I have to replace my Guid with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found by following the hints of IvanStoev.

SQLite stores the Guid by default in a binary format.
Therefor a query like

```
 SELECT * FROM Months WHERE CustomerId = '5cfde6e0-5b3f-437b-84c8-2845b077462d'
```

delivers an empty result.
Using SQLite Adminstrator the Guid is shown with the binary format.
Using the server explorer in VS the Guid is shown with a string format which lead me to the wrong conclusion that this should work.

After setting the option BinaryGUID of the connection string to false the code works fine.

Comment: Before changing your entities, check if setting the following option would help [Store GUID as text](https://connectionstrings.com/sqlite-net-provider/store-guid-as-text/)

Comment: The option works, I updated my answer. Thanks a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your declarations

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; } = new List<Month>();
}

public class Month
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId{get;set;} // you need to add the foreign Key of the customer  ( i will suppose that your foreign key in db called CustomerId
    public string CacheId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")] // and you need to tell EF which column is the foreign key
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

how to use it now

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext())
{
  var customer = context.Customers.First();
  context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
  var shouldContainOneEntry = context.Months.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.Id).ToList();
}
```

hope it will help you

Comment: The ForeignKey should be determined by EF. No need to set it explicitly with the ForeignKey attribute.